# Loopback current context is null sometime

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

In my loopback application i am getting the current logged-in user using `currentcontext` as follows..

```
exports.getCurrentUserId =function(){
  var ctx = loopback.getCurrentContext();
  var accessToken = ctx && ctx.get('accessToken');
  var userId = accessToken && accessToken.userId;
  return userId;
}
```

When i am calling this method `getCurrentUserId`, its working fine sometime, sometimes its giving `null`. Its unpredictable . Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

versions:

```
loopback-connector-mongo:1.15.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Re. `getCurrentContext()`, there is a plan to deprecate this method as it has been unreliable ( see discussion [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1676)). 
However, there is a suggested workaround to [inject Remote Context via Options](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1495).